# Magento 2 admin page wont load. Any suggestions to revert changes?

Tags: magento2, admin, admin-panel, exception

I'm and very new to Magento so please forgive me. Basically I was working on our development server trying to change the layout of our main page. I changed configuration->catalog->catalog->listmode from grid/list to just grid, and now I've encountered a problem.

When every I try to load the admin panel, I am stuck in an infinite loading loop, and when I try to open up the configuration settings, I get sent back to the login screen and I get a "visible section not found" exception. What's weird to me is that the customer facing side is unaffected and fully functional.

Like I said I am very new to Magento and don't really know what I'm doing and don't really know where to begin troubleshooting.

Things I've tried,

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

php bin/magento cache:disable (and then re-enabled)

php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer

rm -rf pub/static/frontend var/cache var/page-cache generated/

These seemed like the only suggestions I could find online, but I don't really know where to go from here. I think I need a way to revert my changes, but I don't know how I would do that outside of the admin panel. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please run below commands and check:-

```
rm -rf pub/static/frontend/* var/cache/* var/page-cache/* generated/*
php bin/magento cache:enabled
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
chmod  -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/
```

Comment: Didn't work. Still having the same issue. Thanks though for trying

Comment: Inspect the page and go to Network tab check the and check the status of the files.

Comment: Everything looks normal except one has a status code of 302. I appears to be something involving the log in credentials.

Comment: I also just noticed that on the log in screen there is another file with the 302 code. https://stage.---.com/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/scripts/invisible.js

Comment: You can check the server logs

Comment: Is this any help? [Tue Aug 01 09:31:43 2023] [access_compat:error] [pid 30135:tid 140617489147648] [client ***.***.***.***:0] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /home/a7cf7ac0/****.**web host**.net/html/pub/.well-known, referer binance.com

Comment: please check  memory_limit, if low increase it 4096M

Comment: memory limit doesn't seem to be the problem. Thanks for trying. I'm gonna take time to try to see if I can find out more about the issue. Appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

Please run below Magento command

rm -rf generated/ var/view_preprocessed/ && php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento s:up && php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento s:s:d -f && php bin/magento c:f && chmod 777 -R var/ generated/ pub/static/

Comment: That did the same thing as the solution before. Thank you though